# Camel Simple Expression

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

My Initial requirement is I need to call the web service for  n no times. If I get the response with in n times I need to update the status code success. If n time exceeds then i need to update the failure in DB. For this I try some POC. I am getting the Exception  while validating the simple expression the Code

```
   <simple>${body.counter} < 4 </simple>
```

I have attached the Entire source code.

```
public class MyBean {
    public String appendCamel(String msg, int i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The Value of i : " + i);
        i = i + 1;
        if (i < 3)
            throw new Exception("Manually Throwed Error " + i);
        else            
        return "Camel ".concat(msg);
    }
    public Message increment(Message m) {
        m.setCounter(m.getCounter() + 1);
        return m;
    }
}
```

Message:

```
    public class Message {
    String text;
    int counter;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message [text=" + text + ", counter=" + counter + "]";
    }

}
```

Camel Context:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <route id="hello">
          <from uri="direct:hello" />
             <camel:doTry>
                <to uri="bean:myBean?method=appendCamel(${body.text},${body.counter})" />
                <to uri="stream:out" />
                <camel:doCatch>
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <camel:to uri="bean:myBean?method=increment(${header.originalvalue})" />
                    <camel:choice>
                        <camel:when>
                            <simple>${body.counter} < 4 </simple>
                            <camel:to uri="direct:hello" />
                        </camel:when>
                        <camel:otherwise>
                            <camel:to uri="stream:out" />
                        </camel:otherwise>
                    </camel:choice>
                </camel:doCatch>
            </camel:doTry>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

MyMain Class

```
public class CamelHelloWorldSpringExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(
            appContext, false);
    try {
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        camelContext.start();
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setCounter(0);
        message.setText("Hello World");
        template.sendBody("direct:hello", message);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Stopping camel context");
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Generated Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 26 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 33; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.javacodegeeks.camel.CamelHelloWorldSpringExample.main(CamelHelloWorldSpringExample.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 33; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2665)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: In XML you need to escape < as &lt; in the XML file

Comment: Like Claus mentioned, you need to escape the "<".